# phantomjs incorrect pdf rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, phantomjs

I am trying to generate a pdf from an html page.
the html is very simple and renders a centered image for each page.

the css i have works correctly when i render the html but it does not when I try to create a pdf out of it with [`node-html-pdf`](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf).

I also created a little express app on github which reproduces the problem:
https://github.com/aschmid/phantomjs2pdf

what is weird in the pdf is that the first 2 pages render correctly.
Then each page after that is 200% the size of the previous one:

[image]

i am sure this is an issue with the css.
also i want to create css rules which will apply to each papersize (letter, tabloid, A4, ....) or orientation (portrait, landscape) and center the image on the page in the pdf.

can somebody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built a replica of your environment in my machine and figured out **adding this code fixed the issue:**

```
html, body {
    max-height:100%;
}
```

At first I thought it was the

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) 
translateY(-50%);
```

trick but it wasn't. My `max-height` tag on the body and html makes sure nothing goes past your page.

Also, and although it's not really right to ask two different things in one question, here's some code to set you off on the track of making this work for landscape and portrait modes:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { 
        .page .imgWrapper img {
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-29%) translateY(87%);
         } }
```

This will find the position of your viewport and center the image for portrait mode too. The weird `translate` values are due to strange interactions with `rotate`. Maybe this is not implemented to work with `html-pdf` but it's a start. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! ill check this out in the next few days and let you know.

Comment: just tested it and it works perfectly. not sure why you added the last `@media` snippet because the above works just fine in either orientation.

Comment: For some reason I wasn't able to test the portrait nor the A3 mode myself. So I attempted to guess it there. Glad to help anyway.

Comment: oh ok. i just tried the letter format. in my usecase i think i will just use letter or A4. it works fine in either portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: You could make a new question about it. Remember to submit the bounty btw :D

Comment: ok thank you. didn't even know i had to submit that separately.

Comment: It does get attributed anyway after the bounty period ends but I wanted to ask it as a favor, because I don't want to risk that day having more than +200 rep and losing the rest (you can't earn more than 200).